# Variable expansion from/within (XML) source file in Ruby

Tags: xml, ruby

I want some slightly 'dynamic' XML source files.  I want some of the element values to be dynamic, or 'expandable'.

I'm providing a value for this variable, from some other source.

```
@Name = 'freezingkiwis'
```

What I want to provide is something like this in an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contact>
    <Name>#{@Name}</Name>
    <Addresses />
    <Phones />
</Contact>
```

When opening/reading the file (presumably File.new or File.read) I want to then 'expand' the @Name variable, set previously.

Is there something that will do this immediately for me, or am I going to have to parse this XML (possibly now as a REXML::Document) and do this manually myself?

(i.e. possibly replace the  element value with this...)

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html), a Ruby templating engine used for example in Rails. Then you can write any Ruby code, including variable substitution, between the `<% %>` tags. On the other hand don't use this solution if the XML template itself is editable by users - this will lead to a severe security hole.

Comment: ERB was exactly what I was after, I just hadn't discovered it at the time. All over it these days.